# Why does "E89: No write since last change" error not occur when commands are joined with bar?

Tags: buffers, error, hidden-buffers

I have `:set hidden` set in my `~/.vimrc`.

First I did this:

- `vim foo bar`
- `:bn`<kbd>Enter</kbd>
- <kbd>i</kbd>`hello`<kbd>Esc</kbd>
- `:bp`<kbd>Enter</kbd>
- `:bd#`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

The `:bd#` command leads to this error:

```
E89: No write since last change for buffer 2 (add ! to override)
```

This is expected behavior.

Then I did this:

- `vim foo bar`
- `:bn`<kbd>Enter</kbd>
- <kbd>i</kbd>`hello`<kbd>Esc</kbd>
- `:bp | bd#`<kbd>Enter</kbd>
- `:ls`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

This time `:bp | bd#`<kbd>Enter</kbd> did not lead to any error. The output of `:ls`<kbd>Enter</kbd> shows that the buffer for `bar` is still present.

Why did the `E89` error did not occur in the second set of steps?

Comment: cannot reproduce. I always get `E89 no write...`. Please try with `vim --clean`